# How I can unite resulsts of loop "for" in one matrix

Tags: loops, for-loop, scilab

I have a loop that makes 40 matrixs 3x7. I want to save all matrices of this loop in one matrix 120x7

```
n=40

for i = 1:n

A=[
   1, 0, 0, ITRF(i,1), 0,          ITRF(i,3), -ITRF(i,2);
   0, 1, 0, ITRF(i,2), -ITRF(i,3), 0,         ITRF(i,1);
   0, 0, 1, ITRF(i,3), ITRF(i,2), -ITRF(i,1), 0
]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of matrix as shelves that you can pile over each other or put them side by side as long as they have compatible dimensions.

Consider `A` and `B`, you can

- put them side by side by doing `[A, B]` or `[A B]`, if the have the same number of rows.
- put one on top of the other by doing `[A; B]`, if the have the same number of columns.

In your case, I understand you want to pile matrices `X` of size 3-by-7 over each other. You can set an empty matrix `M` and use it to store all results:

```
M = []; \\empty matrix

for i = 1:n
    X = ... \\calculate matrix A (3-by-7)

    M = [M; X] \\put resulting A at the end of M in each loop
end
```

By the end of the `for` loop, `M` will have size 3n-by-7.